# Python program does not return the value bonus

Tags: python

I'm having trouble with one of my very first programs for a python class. this is supposed to take three values which are calculated in two different functions (one with and one without bonus). Then I want to output all the results in the main function. As you can see, I'm having problems printing out the results correctly. If I input some variables that are going to return salary, bonus, base, months worked and commission, I should get all these variables back if months worked > 3 and without bonus if months worked < 3. It should also subtract or add an extra value based off two other if statements.

```
#calculate income rates with sales, bonus, comission
def income(sales):
    if (sales > 1000000):
        bonus = 100000
        commission = .35
        salary = 2000 + sales + bonus + (sales * commission)

    elif(sales >= 500001 and sales <= 1000000):
        bonus = 5000
        commission = .28
        salary = 2000 + sales + bonus + (sales * commission)

    elif (sales >= 100001 and sales <= 500000):
        bonus = 1000
        commission = .15
        salary = 2000 + sales + bonus + (sales * commission)

    elif (sales >= 10000 and sales <= 100000):
        bonus = 0
        commission = .02
        salary = 2000 + sales + bonus + (sales * commission)

    else:
        bonus = 0
        commission = 0
        salary = 2000 + sales + bonus + (sales * commission)

    return salary
    return bonus
    return commission

#calculate income rates with sales and commission, no bonus
def calc_no_bonus(sales):
    bonus = 0
    if (sales > 1000000):
        commission = .35
        salary = 2000 + sales + (sales * commission)

    elif(sales >= 500001 and sales <= 1000000):
        commission = .28
        salary = 2000 + sales + (sales * commission)

    elif (sales >= 100001 and sales <= 500000):
        commission = .15
        salary = 2000 + sales + (sales * commission)

    elif (sales >= 10000 and sales <= 100000):
        commission = .02
        salary = 2000 + sales + (sales * commission)
    else:
        commission = 0
        salary = 2000 + sales + (sales * commission)

    return salary
    return commission

def main():
    name = input("What is your name? ")
    sales = float(input("Input your annual sales: "))
    vacation = int(input("How many vacation days have you taken? "))
    months = int(input("How many years have you been with the company?             Please enter in number of months: "))
    base = 2000
    salary = 0
    bonus= 0
    commission = 0
    if (months < 3):
        salary = calc_no_bonus(sales)    
    else:
        salary = income(sales)
        bonus = income(bonus)
        commission = income(commission)
    #For salespeople who have been with the company for more than 5 years and who have made sales greater than $100,000 an additional bonus of $1000 is added
        if (months > 60 and sales > 100000):
            salary = income(sales) + 1000

#If a salesperson has taken more than 3 vacation days in a month, their pay gets reduced
#by $200
    if (vacation > 3):
        salary = income(sales) - 200 

    print("Your total salary is $", format(salary, ',.2f'), sep='')
    print("This consists of: \n your sales of $", format(sales, ',.2f'), sep='')
    print("your base of $", base)
    print("your bonus of $", bonus)
    print("your commission of $", commission)


main()
```

result:

```
What is your name? j
Input your annual sales: 1000000
How many vacation days have you taken? 6
How many years have you been with the company? Please enter in number of months: 2
Your total salary is $1,286,800.00
This consists of: 
 your sales of $1,000,000.00
your base of $ 2000
your bonus of $ 0
your commission of $ 0

What is your name? j
Input your annual sales: 1000000
How many vacation days have you taken? 8
How many years have you been with the company? Please enter in number of months: 4
Your total salary is $1,286,800.00
This consists of: 
 your sales of $1,000,000.00
your base of $ 2000
your bonus of $ 2000
your commission of $ 2000

The syntax of salary:
1,000,000 sales
  350,000 comission
  100,000 bonus
    2,000 base
salary should be 1,452,000?
```

Answer (score 2):

First return exits(that means 2nd return does not work) 
To overcome this change the syntax -
 `return (salary, bonus, commision)`
Edited - This reurns the output as a tupple, following code will give you an idea of how to use it for taking the output

```
def income(sales):
    salary = sales*0.1
    bonus = sales*0.2
    commision = sales *0.3
    return (salary, bonus, commision)

sample = 1000
income2 = income(sample)
print income2[1]
```

`

Comment: Thanks. What's the difference between: return salary return bonus return commission and return (salary, bonus, commission). I get this error when I edit it that way: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'in

Comment: @JuliePixie refer edited answer, changing the output to access the tuple will take care of the error

Comment: That's a little more advanced than I'm dealing with. We haven't even gotten to tuples yet.  It's a bit over my head. I assume by print income2[1] that means print salary[1]after if months >60 and sales > 100000 but that returns a syntax error

Comment: Is there a way to do this program without tuples until I can get a better understanding?

Comment: I'm not really sure how to do it otherwise, best way is to write a each function separately & test it, syntax errors will be pretty straight forward to identify.

Comment: thank you. It's not a must have for me to pass the assignment, i'm just curious. I'll post when I talk to my instructor.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to return more than one value, you have to return them all in a single statement. You can then "unpack" the results by assigning the return value to multiple variables.

For example:

```
def income(sales):
    ...
    return salary, bonus, commission
...
salary, bonus, commission = income(sales)
```

Comment: When I try to change my return statement like that I get this error:ypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'int'

Comment: also result now is off:

Comment: What is your name? julie
Input your annual sales: 1000000
How many vacation days have you taken? 5
How many years have you been with the company? Please enter in number of months: 5
Your total salary is $1,287,000.00
This consists of: 
 your sales of $1,000,000.00
your base of $ 2000
your bonus of $ (7000, 0, 0)
your commission of $ (2000.28, 0, 0)
>>>

Comment: Ok i seem to be getting it to work other than the if months > 60 and if vacation > 3 parts. those return the tuple error